# Django rest framework filtering and grouping items in serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, grouping

I have models like this:

```
class schoolCycle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class measurements(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    school_cycle_id = models.ForeignKey(schoolCycle,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='measurements')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class aspects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    measurement_id = models.ForeignKey(measurements,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='aspects')

class standards(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    aspect_id = models.ForeignKey(aspects,on_delete =models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='standards')
```

as can be seen, "standard" refers an 'aspect' and aspect refers 'a measurement" and measurement refers a 'school cycle' as foreign key.
in want to create a seriallizer like this:

```
  [{ "measurement 1" : { 
                   "school cycle 1" :{
                                      "aspect 1": {
                                                     {"standard 1" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 2" : ...},
                                                   }

                                      "aspect 2": {
                                                     {"standard 3" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 4" : ...},
                                                   }
                                      }
                  "school cycle 2" :{
                                      "aspect 3": {
                                                     {"standard 5" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 6" : ...},
                                                   }

                                      "aspect 4": {
                                                     {"standard 7" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 8" : ...},
                                                   }
                                      }
  "measurement 2" : { 
                   "school cycle 3" :{
                                      "aspect 5": {
                                                     {"standard 9" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 10" : ...},
                                                   }

                                      "aspect 6": {
                                                     {"standard 11" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 12" : ...},
                                                   }
                                      }
                  "school cycle 4" :{
                                      "aspect 7": {
                                                     {"standard 13" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 14" : ...},
                                                   }

                                      "aspect 8": {
                                                     {"standard 15" : ...},
                                                     {"standard 16" : ...},
                                                   }
                                      }

     }]
```

Meaning i want to serialize by grouping aspects that have the same school cycle and measurement under their own key.

How to achieve this kind of grouping in Django rest framework? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SchoolCycleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    measurements = MeasurementsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = schoolCycle
        fields = '__all__'

class MeasurementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    aspects = AspectsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = measurements
        fields = '__all__'

class AspectsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    standards = StandardsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = aspects
        fields = '__all__'

class StandardsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = standards
        fields = '__all__'

# note that it's good practice to name your models starting with a capital letter.
```